# Accessing JSONObject properties in JSP using EL expression

Tags: java, json, jsp, el

I have a servlet that turns a String into a JSONObject as below:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject("{'someKey':'someValue'}"); 
//sending it to the JSP with RequestDispatcher
request.setAttribute("jsonObject", myObject)
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Now in JSP, I try to access it using EL expression `${jsonObject.someKey}` and I get the following error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.json.JSONObject' does not have the property 'someKey'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps.

```
${jsonObject.get("someKey")}
```

Comment: 2 years later it helped :)